# Convert String "2008-02-10T12:29:33.000" to a Date with the same format 2008-02-10T12:29:33.000 in Java

Tags: java, string, transform, simpledateformat

I have an ArrayList that contains strings like 2008-02-10T12:29:33.000

```
[2008-02-11T12:29:33.000, 2008-02-10T12:29:33.000]...
```

I want to sort this ArrayList in natural order. For this I have to convert this strings into a Date I quess.
The order after sorting sorting the ArrayList above shoult be:

```
[2008-02-10T12:29:33.000, 2008-02-11T12:29:33.000]
```

The programming language that I use is Java.

Comment: Agreed. It's just a matter of parsing and calling [Collections.sort(List)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)

Comment: I see that months are preceded by zero when needed. Does it also apply to rest of date elements like hours, minutes, seconds? If yes then as @gtgaxiola mentioned in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30805122/1393766) you can simply sort it alphabetically (which is natural order for strings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you need to do any conversion, as there is a natural order of those strings (at least I can't see a counterexample).

So  `Collections.sort()` should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I have not tried the sort as strings but it works. Ty!

Comment: @NellyJunior Notice that this will work only if used data formatting supports leading zeroes like `01:02:03.004`. Example: http://ideone.com/3vUuJu

Comment: @Pshemo good catch!  This is exactly where the 'counterexample' could happen, but it seems is proper ISO 8601 format (so is always zero-padded)

Answer (score 4):

Although you could just sort the strings, I would store those dates as [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)s instead of strings and keep them that way. That will make manipulating them much easier.

The transformation could look like:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("2008-02-11T12:29:33.000", "2008-02-10T12:29:33.000");
List<LocalDateTime> dates = list.stream().map(LocalDateTime::parse).collect(toList());
```

(this works because your strings are in proper ISO format).

And then sorting is as simple as:

```
Collections.sort(dates);
```

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted...

Comment: no idea... This does the trick

Comment: @assylias possibly some ppl still don't know what java 8 is :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> dates = new ArrayList<String>();
dates.add("2008-02-11T12:29:33.000");
dates.add("2008-02-10T12:29:33.000");
Collections.sort(dates);
for (String date : dates)
{
  System.out.println(date);
}
```

Comment: it sort based on string not date

Comment: @nafas: actually, the XML date format is designed so that sorting as strings is identical to sorting as dates.